# MySQL Community - Scaling

Tags: mysql, sharding

I am working in an environment that is under extreme load. It is a DB used by about a thousand users with one application. This application does thousands of queries against the DB. We have noticed significant performance degradation over time and are looking for a long-term solution to this problem. Of course, query optimization is one of the tasks we are working on, and we are also optimizing indexes; however, this will not be enough to see the performance gains we need.

I have worked in SQL Server for several years but my MySQL knowledge is limited. To start scaling MySQL, I've researched Sharding, but as we are using MySQL community edition, I'm nervous that this will cause more headaches than it's worth. The only other possibility is to re-design the application, specifically how it pulls data from the DB, but I'd rather not do that.

So my question is, is sharing worthwhile to pursue? Is it feasible without an enterprise edition of MySQL? Is there another possibility you could recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time=1`.  Wait a day.  Use `pt-query-digest` to identify the 'worst' could of queries.  Then let's discuss them.  Sometimes it involves the trivial addition of a 'composite' index.

That is, Slow queries is almost always the cause for scaling problems.

If we eliminate that as a problem, *then* we can discuss sharding and other non-trivial approaches.

We must see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and other clues of what is going on.